# Why traditional GetProcAddress to std::function is not working straightforward

Tags: c++, c++17, dynamic-import

As in the title I'd like to convert GetProcAddress into std::function. Yes, there are multiple solutions in stack overflow, but none actually explains why those workarounds are needed. I can't really understand the exact error message and why it happens. The sample source is simple:

```
#include <functional>
#include <Windows.h>

using fn_NtAllocateVirtualMemory = NTSTATUS (NTAPI*)(
        HANDLE      ProcessHandle,
        PVOID*      BaseAddress,
        ULONG_PTR   ZeroBits,
        PSIZE_T     RegionSize,
        ULONG       AllocationType,
        ULONG       Protect
    );

int main()
{
    std::function<fn_NtAllocateVirtualMemory> myFn(reinterpret_cast<fn_NtAllocateVirtualMemory>(0xDEADBABE));
}
```

( https://godbolt.org/z/FhaeLA )

So, my question is why is it wrong?

---

Related:
I also tried this:
[Function pointer to multiple argument C++11 std::function: Templating GetProcAddress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558875/function-pointer-to-multiple-argument-c11-stdfunction-templating-getprocadd)
But it also failed to compile ( https://godbolt.org/z/1wSDZj )

I've also found this topic:
[C++ Dynamically load arbitrary function from DLL into std::function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249465/c-dynamically-load-arbitrary-function-from-dll-into-stdfunction)
Which might work *(I haven't yet tried, I'll do it soon)* but I'm trying to understand why this kind of cryptic looking huge boilerplate is necessary.

---

Notes:

- Obviously 0xDEADBEEF is going to be replaced with the necessary address.
- I'm using Visual Studio 2019 to compile, but obviously any generic answer is welcomed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::function` takes signature as template parameter, not pointer.

So it should be:

```
using fn_NtAllocateVirtualMemory = NTSTATUS NTAPI (
        HANDLE      ProcessHandle,
        PVOID*      BaseAddress,
        ULONG_PTR   ZeroBits,
        PSIZE_T     RegionSize,
        ULONG       AllocationType,
        ULONG       Protect
    );

int main()
{
    std::function<fn_NtAllocateVirtualMemory> myFn(
        reinterpret_cast<fn_NtAllocateVirtualMemory*>(0xDEADBABE));
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Note that you should change the order of NTAPI & NTSTATUS, because this way it's failing. Else, it's cool :)

Comment: @original.roland: order changed.