# Functionals and dynamic loading dll exported functions

Tags: c++, function, templates

following other discussions ([Discussion 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249465/c-dynamically-load-arbitrary-function-from-dll-into-stdfunction) and [Discussion 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558875/function-pointer-to-multiple-argument-c11-stdfunction-templating-getprocadd)) I wrote some pice of code to have a template based helper function to synamic load functions exported from a dll.

It works fine, but just if the functions exported from the dll are cdecl functions. I've troubles if they  have different calling convenctions and I'm looking for a good suggestion.

Here some of my code:

```
template <typename Ret, typename... Args >
Ret ExecuteIt(LPCSTR funName,  Args... Pack)
{
    std::map<LPCSTR, CGenericHolder*>::iterator it;

    it = m_functionsMap.find(funName);

    if (it != m_functionsMap.end())
    {
        CGenericHolder* tmpObj = it->second;

            if (tmpObj->IsValid())
            {
                CVarFuncHolder<Ret(Args...)>* tmpObjF = dynamic_cast<CVarFuncHolder<Ret(Args...)>*>(tmpObj);
                if (tmpObjF)
                    return tmpObjF->ExecuteIt()(Pack...);
                else
                    throw std::bad_cast("Object doesn't match the function");
            }
    }


    throw std::bad_function_call("Function not exists");
};

template <typename T>
bool MapMemberFunction(LPCSTR funName, int ordinal = -1)
{
    CVarFuncHolder<T>* newFun = new CVarFuncHolder<T>();
    bool rv = true;

    try
    {
        newFun->Assign(funName, loadDllFunc<T>(funName,ordinal));
        m_functionsMap[funName] = newFun;
    }
    catch (const std::invalid_argument& e)
    {

#ifdef _DEBUG 
        OutputDebugStringA(e.what());
#endif

        delete newFun;
        rv = false;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return rv;
};


template <typename T>
std::function<T> loadDllFunc(LPCSTR funcName, int ordinal) 
{
    // Load DLL.

    // Check if DLL is loaded.
    if (!m_dllHinst)
        throw std::invalid_argument("Dll not loaded");

    // Locate function in DLL.

    FARPROC lpfnGetProcessID = ::GetProcAddress(m_dllHinst, (ordinal >= 0) ? MAKEINTRESOURCEA(ordinal) : funcName);

    // Check if function was located.
    if (!lpfnGetProcessID) 
        throw std::invalid_argument("Function call not found");

    // Create function object from function pointer.
    auto f = CastFromFPtrToFunction<T>(lpfnGetProcessID);

    return f;
   }

 template<typename Signature>
 std::function<Signature> CastFromFPtrToFunction(FARPROC f)
 {
     return std::function<Signature>(reinterpret_cast<Signature*>(f));
 }
```

Now,

I map the function that I want in this way

```
if (!MapMemberFunction<long (long, unsigned char, unsigned char)>("Func name"))
        return false;
```

I use the function in this way:

```
auto rv = ExecuteIt<long>("Func name", par1, par2, par3);
```

And all goes fine if the function was written using cdecl calling convenction, but the app crashes if the function has a different calling convention.

I tried to map the function in a different way

```
MapMemberFunction<long APIENTRY (long, unsigned char, unsigned char)>("Func name"));
```

but in this latter, I have a problem calling the Excute method, because the dynamic_cast fails.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: It looks for me that the only way is to explicitly declare the calling convention. There is no way you can say what calling convention function is using in the dll. So, the calling convention should be the part of function pointer.

Comment: I suppose you could get more people looking your problem if you considerably reduce the size of your example, such that it would be a dozen lines or so.

Comment: @Tihran, what do you mean? How should I change the function pointer template in your opinion?

Comment: @3Hyde well, for example `double (__fastcall*)(int, int)` for the function that returns double, expects 2 ints and has call convention "fastcall"

Comment: @Tihran, so you mean that I should work around the code that I've already tried: MapMemberFunction<long APIENTRY (long, unsigned char, unsigned char)>("Func name"));
It stores correctly the the function as stdcall in that case, but I fail during the dynamic_cast (as I said previously), exactly here:
CVarFuncHolder<Ret(Args...)>* tmpObjF = dynamic_cast<CVarFuncHolder<Ret(Args...)>*>(tmpObj);

Comment: @Tihran I followed your suggestion to work around an explicit declaration of which type of call the function have and I replace the dynamic_cast which failed with a standard C cast. I mean CVarFuncHolder<Ret(Args...)>* tmpObjF = (CVarFuncHolder<Ret(Args...)>*)tmpObj; 
It works, but at this point my big question is: why dynamic_cast is failing?!

Comment: @3Hyde well, I don't think dynamic cast meant to work in such cases. All you need is reinterpret_cast here. Dynamic cast is meant to be used for OOP-casts when you have RTTI enabled. In this case - this is just a function pointer, and typeif() works not as expected.